# LinkedIn - All LinkedIn links on my website get a 500 error

Tags: html, hyperlink, linkedin-api

I'm trying to link a button to my LinkedIn profile, but it's not working.

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="profile_pic" src="Images/profilepic.jpeg">
    <img src="Images/name.png">
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/katrinatheo"><img class="social" src="Images/linbutton.png"></a>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.social {
    float: right;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

My button shows up just fine and everything. But every link (including non-image ones), do not work. They bring up a 500 Internal Server Error page. I use JustHost.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (working and syntactically correct code) so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: 500 error means publicly you don't have permission to read. You need to update the permissions on your images, and the parent directory on the server, usually to something like 644.

Comment: @setek - I checked and my index.html and stylesheet.css are both set at 644. I can't change the permissions for my images folder to 644 or they won't show up.

Comment: @remus - I don't think it has to do with my code now that I am looking more into it. I think it has something to do with something along the lines of what setek suggested.

Comment: Hmm, have you made sure the image path is definitely correct? Do you know what the permissions are on the parent directory? You might want to chat to tech support of your host.

Comment: @setek My mom has the parent directory, and she has a CS degree so I figured she'd have it set up correctly. But I'll check with her, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I was just putting "http://www.google.com" but when I put "https://www.google.com" it worked. It must have to use a secure website. Thanks for your suggestions everyone!

Answer (score -1):

Here are the solutions..now it working fine...fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/6SK7F/

Html

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="profile_pic" src="Images/profilepic.jpeg">
    <img src="Images/name.png">
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/katrinatheo"  target="_blank"><img class="social" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/h/t/2/I/K/linkbutton-bo-md.png"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.social {
    float: right;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: working fine in my side...i think you dont have some permissions.....try another browsers or computers...

Comment: It's not working even for regular, just text, links. I checked my permissions and both files are under 644.